# Dispersion Relation in Spin Chains in Terms of Quantum Speed Limits

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dispersion, spin-chains

Going off the dispersion relation derived by [He and Guo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02400)
$$E_k = \sqrt{\left(\frac{J}{2}\right)^2 + h^2 + Jh\cos k}$$
Where $J$ is the nearest neighbour interaction strength and $h$ is the external field strength. This means that our group velocity can be expressed as (in the thermodynamic limit as the number of spins $N\rightarrow \infty$):
$$v_g=\frac{dE_k}{dk}=\frac{-Jh\sin k}{2 E_k}$$
Now an estimate for the Quantum Speed Limit time $\tau$ of a system is given by:
$$\tau = \frac{\pi \hbar}{2 E}$$
which would imply that our group velocity in terms of $\tau$ is given by:
$$v_g = \frac{\tau Jh \sin k}{\pi \hbar}$$
Intuitively I would say that this doesn't make sense since it's expected that longer transition-times between states would lead to slower velocities but this is indicating the exact opposite. My suspicion is that I am making an error somewhere (or I'm misunderstanding something) that I cannot see, in which case my question would be where's the error in my reasoning?

For the very unlikely case that this result is correct, how would one interpret this?

Comment: Why does this group velocity $v_g$ have units of energy?

Comment: @jwimberley Good point. Had a quick look at the paper I linked, in eqn6 they define the quasimomentum space to be dimensionless as the FT is going from the discrete dimensionless variable $n$ rather than from a continuous variable with units of position. Therefore since taking a derivative w.r.t. a dimensionless quantity preserves the units, you get units of energy again.

Comment: ... and since the proper definition is $v_g=\frac{d\omega}{dk}$ and we are using $E$, one would also account for a missing $\hbar$ since $E=\hbar \omega$. Then with this and another transformation $k \rightarrow ka$ for some lattice-spacing constant $a$ with units of distance we get the correct units for $v_g$